# Linux/PHP Question

Tags: php, linux

I'm a pretty Huge n00b when it comes to Linux

```
exec ('whoami', $output, $return);
echo $return;
```

// Outputs 127
Which means the command is not executing.  I can get it to execute when I root into the server.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: He wants his `exec ('whoami' ...` to execute whenever he logs on.

Comment: What do `echo posix_getlogin();`, `echo posix_getpgrp()`, and all the `safe_mode_` ini settings say?

Comment: echo posix_getlogin(); and echo posix_getgr() return nothing.  Originally safe_mode was turned on, but I turned it off in the php.ini file, but the problem still occured.

Answer (score 1):

If you try this:

```
<?php
exec('whoami');
?>
```

you should be presented with PHP's username.. If you try this:

```
<?php
exec('whoami', $output, $return);
print_r($output);
?>
```

you should see that $output is an array containing anything the shell output.

The return value, according to the [PHP manual](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php), "return status of the executed command will be written to this variable." - is that what you want?

Comment: What I Really need is to exec pdftk, but any command I try to exec using the PHP function exec() does not work. Even if I try exec('whoami'); it returns 127.  I'm thinking this is related to permissions or something, but I have no idea how or what to do to change the permissions to get this fixed.

Comment: Running this: 

exec('whoami', $output, $return);
print_r($output); 

echo $return; 


Returns This: 
Array ( ) 127

Comment: Apparently the 127 code means "file not found". You probably just need to use the absolute path, ( e.g. /usr/local/bin/whoami ).

Answer (score 1):

127 exit status is indicative of a missing command. Perhaps `whoami` is not on the system or maybe your web server configuration has you jailed in some way or you are being restricted via [safe_mode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php)/[open_basedir](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php).

To verify you can try running:

```
exec('which whoami', $output, $return);
print_r($output);
echo $return;
```

If you are presented with an empty array and a return code of `0`, then the `whoami` executable is currently inaccessible from your web server/PHP setup.

To check safe_mode, open_basedir settings, call [phpinfo](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php).

Answer (score -1):

Why not just do something like:

```
<?php

$var = `whoami`;

echo $var;

?>
```